# Programmatically Add UIView to the Bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I've have a UITableViewController in my storyboard. I'm trying to add a Google ad banner view(which is basically a UIView) to the bottom of it.

I know I can't just drag a UIView in Interface Builder and place it to the bottom of the UITableView. Therefore I opted for adding the ad banner view programmatically. This what I coded:

```
  let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSize(size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 50), flags: 0))
  bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  view.addSubview(bannerView)

  let bannerViewPinToTheBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                                    attribute: .Bottom,
                                                    relatedBy: .Equal,
                                                    toItem: cate,
                                                    attribute: .Bottom,
                                                    multiplier: 1.0,
                                                    constant: 0.0)

  let bannerViewCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                             attribute: .CenterY,
                                             relatedBy: .Equal,
                                             toItem: view,
                                             attribute: .CenterY,
                                             multiplier: 1.0,
                                             constant: 0.0)

  let bannerViewWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                           attribute: .Height,
                                           relatedBy: .Equal,
                                           toItem: nil,
                                           attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                                           multiplier: 1.0,
                                           constant: 300.0)

  let bannerViewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                            attribute: .Height,
                                            relatedBy: .Equal,
                                            toItem: nil,
                                            attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                                            multiplier: 1.0,
                                            constant: 50.0)

  // add the constraints
  bannerView.addConstraints([bannerViewPinToTheBottom, bannerViewCenterY, bannerViewWidth, bannerViewHeight])
```

When I ran the app and visit the UITableViewController, I get the following error message:

```
2016-07-09 22:00:36.653 En Yakın[20923:1114504] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d04cc40 GADBannerView:0x7a8a8c70.bottom == UITableView:0x7bac8e00.bottom>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2016-07-09 22:00:36.655 En Yakın[20923:1114504] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
    Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d04cc40 GADBannerView:0x7a8a8c70.bottom == UITableView:0x7bac8e00.bottom>
    Container hierarchy: 
<GADBannerView: 0x7a8a8c70; frame = (0 0; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7af35fb0>>
   | <GADAdView: 0x7af3c520; frame = (0 0; 320 50); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7af3b810>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7af3c640>>
   |    | <UIScrollView: 0x7b28a000; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7af3c340>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7af37200>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7af48b50; frame = (-39 -5.5; 36 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7af48c80>> - (null)
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7d04bae0; frame = (-5.5 -39; 2.5 36); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ae1e830>> - (null)
   |    | <UIWebView: 0x7a8d20e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a8d21b0>>
   |    |    | <_UIWebViewScrollView: 0x7b34b600; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7af46bd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7af468d0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    | <UIWebBrowserView: 0x7b298a00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7af44600>; layer = <UIWebLayer: 0x7a8d30c0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <LegacyTileHostLayer: 0x7a8d32e0> (layer)
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7d04bc00; frame = (-39 -5.5; 36 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d04ac40>> - (null)
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7d04b3a0; frame = (-5.5 -39; 2.5 36); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d04ae40>> - (null)
    View not found in container hierarchy: <UITableView: 0x7bac8e00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ae0a480>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ae04220>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 264}>
    That view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
2016-07-09 22:00:36.677 En Yakın[20923:1114504] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d04cc40 GADBannerView:0x7a8a8c70.bottom == UITableView:0x7bac8e00.bottom> view:<GADBannerView: 0x7a8a8c70; frame = (0 0; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7af35fb0>>'
```

What should be changed in order to perform correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> I've have a UITableViewController in my storyboard. I'm trying to add a Google ad banner view(which is basically a UIView) to the bottom of it.

Don't add your own subviews to a table view. Instead, have a table view *and* the ad banner view. So, your view hierarchy will look like this:

```
mainview
    tableview
    adbannerview
```

Now, of course, this means that `mainview` no longer can be controlled by a UITableViewController, because it isn't a tableview. So you need to configure a *contained view controller*, so that you have a view controller hierarchy parallel to the view hierarchy you are constructing:

```
MainViewController
    TableViewController
```

Comment: So you say, throw out the UITableViewController and go with a basic UIViewController by adding a UITableView and the UIView(my ad banner) into it?

Comment: Did you read what I said? The whole point is that I showed you how _not_ to throw out the UITableViewController.

Comment: I read it but got confused a little bit. Now I get it. Sorry about that. Although could you please be more specific on achieving it.

Comment: On achieving what? What part do you not know how to do?